# beebole pure js subtemplate for textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates

Can any one help me writting a sub template for textarea using pure.js???

```
var data = { 
        "Fields": { 
            "User_Name": { 
                "FieldName": "User_Name", 
                "Caption": "User Name", 
                "HTMLTemplate": "<input type=\"text\" value=\"\" maxlength=\"\" autocomplete=\"off\" name=\"\" id=\"\">",
                "Type" : "textarea"
            }, 
            "Password": { 
                "FieldName": "Password", 
                "Caption": "Password", 
                "HTMLTemplate": "<input type=\"text\" value=\"\" maxlength=\"\" autocomplete=\"off\" name=\"\" id=\"\">" 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

in above code, if i give type as textarea automatically a text area should be formed, if type is text, a text field should be displayed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would like to overwrite the `HTMLTemplate` property?

```
for(fields in data){
    for(field in data[fields]){
        if(data[fields][field]['Type'] == 'textarea') data[fields][field]['HTMLTemplate'] = '<textarea></textarea>';
    }
}
```

This snippet will loop you object and overwrite the `HTMLTemplate` property if the `Type` property == 'textarea'. But why you don't use the `HTMLTemplate`property correctly from the start?

Comment: actually HTMLtemplate is for referance, i dont need that at all, if the type is textarea i need to get one thats all
will try your code

Comment: can u plz tell me where exactly i shd use this